# Ember.js ListView handling events

Tags: ember.js

Ember.js rc1 version has introduced different event/actions handling. It seems to be not possible to have access to the event and controller's context in one method - although it was possible in older ember releaseS.

Checkout jsFiddle that describes my problem:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macpit/npdCy/)

```
var controller = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    itemSelected: function(context) {
        console.log(context);
        this.set('name', context.fullName);
    },        
    content: [
        {fullName: "aaaa"},
        {fullName: "bbbb"},
        {fullName: "cccc"},
    ]
});
var view = Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(template),
    controller: controller,
    click: function(event) {          
        console.log("clicked");
    }
});
```

Currently I need to have two callbacks: one in a controller to get context(list item) and second one in a view to get an event and element.
It'd be much more convenient to have both in one callback only. The logic I'm developing needs both at the same time - it's a selection model that needs to have access to controller's content and the element that the event was generated on.

Any ideas how to do this in newest ember version????
Thanks,
qmacpit

Comment: Unfortunately, a close reading of the action helper source reveals that `event` is never passed to the action. If you can describe exactly what you need the specific element for, I might be able to describe an alternate way to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for your comment:] We need it because for many lists we use in our project we use a SelectionModel class. It is a piece of logic that handles all things related to performed selection. It combines event and context, decorates our views(that's why we'd like to have an event and clicked element) and keeps track of selected elements.

Comment: I think that the combination of the previous and current approach would be perfect. I really liked event.context property:]